# 404 Error with PhysiJS in Angular

Tags: angular, physijs

I am trying to get Physijs running with Angular. The Three Scene is working fine so far but I dont get any Physics effects.

I installed the following with npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/physijs-browserify

My corresponding Component.ts part for initializing Physijs looks as follows:

```
declare function require(name: string);
declare var THREE: any;
const Physijs = require('physijs-browserify')(THREE);
Physijs.scripts.worker = '/libs/physi-worker.js';
Physijs.scripts.ammo = '/libs/ammo.js';
```

I am always getting the following Error in the Chrome Console.:

physi.js:393 GET http://localhost:4200/libs/physi-worker.js 404 (Not Found)

I also tried the full path from the node_modules but that worked neither:

```
Physijs.scripts.worker = "../testproject/node_modules/physijs-browserify/libs/physi-worker.js"
```

The physi.js file at line 393 looks as follows:

```
this._worker = new Worker( Physijs.scripts.worker || 'physi-worker.js' );
```

I even tried to add the script in the .angular-cli.json but also that had not any effect:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/physijs-browserify/libs/physi-worker.js"
]
```

Am I doing something wrong in declaring the path to the physi-worker.js? Or could there be another problem? I am new to Angular and JavaScript so maybe it is an obvious issue.

I would appreciate your help a lot.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are not available if they are not defined as an asset in the .angular-cli.json or they are located in the assets folder.

So you have two possibilities:

1. Put the files into the assets folder then your code should look like that:

   ```
   Physijs.scripts.worker = 'assets/physi-worker.js';
   Physijs.scripts.ammo = 'assets/ammo.js';
   ```
2. Add the folder that hosts the files to the assets configuration in the cli:

   ```
   "assets": [
   "assets",
   "favicon.ico"
   "./node_modules/physijs-browserify/libs"
   ],
   ```

I would prefer the first option.